# by instance() showing red line in android studio after updating android studio 4 in kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin-coroutines, kodein

[image]by instance() showing red line after updating android studio 4

private val factory: SelectHospitalViewModelFactory by instance()

Comment: Please share the error message

Comment: This is an issue with the new type inference of kotlin  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-38259. You can disable it in AS settings

Answer (score 0):

[image]step 1-
Setting-> Kotlin Compiler" [image] »

step 2-
could you please disable new type inference in IDE by unchecking checkbox "Enable new type inference algorithm..." in Preferences -> Kotlin Compiler